# How to delete a file in imageJ macro

Tags: macros, imagej

I am trying to write a macro so in imageJ. I want to apply this macro to different image file.

So in the beginning, I save the selected picture with temp.jpg file name

```
saveAs("Jpeg", "/Users/pathreskoo/Desktop/IHC/temp.jpg");
```

After I finish the process, I want to delete the file
I try

```
ok = file.delete("/Users/pathreskoo/Desktop/IHC/temp.jpg");
```

But the file was not removed. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

ImageJ macro is case sensitive. Try using File.delete, not file.delete.

https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#File.delete